# Visual Studio 2013 Preview with Update: ASPX view engine inserts extra spaces

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, visual-studio-2013

Our application uses simple aspx syntax to show, for example, version of the server:

```
<h1>Server Engine v<%=System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Server.Engine)).GetName().Version %></h1>
// "Server Engine v3.6.1268.0"
```

It works just fine in VS 2010 and 2012 but in VS 2013 we get in source:

```
<h1>Server Engine v   3.6.1268.0   </h1>
```

It looks the same in browser, but in another place we form Url with aspx syntax and the resulting Url has those strange symbols in path.
Here is the code:

```
var folderUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':' + port + '<%=Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/')%>/';
```

Result in source:

```
var folderUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':' + port + '     /';
```

The same project works just fine from VS2012. Why this happens and how to avoid this problem?

Update1:

Here these strange symbols in HEX view:

```
00000002E0: 3A 27 20 2B 20 70 6F 72 │ 74 20 2B 20 27 EF BB BF  :' + port + 'п»ї
00000002F0: EF BB BF EF BB BF EF BB │ BF EF BB BF 2F 27 3B 0A  п»їп»їп»їп»ї/';◙
```

Update2:

I added:

```
<%=System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileVersionInfo %>
```

to detect current IIS version. The result is the same for both VS2012 and VS2013:

```
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe InternalName: iisexpress.exe OriginalFilename: iisexpress.exe.mui FileVersion: 8.0.8418.0 (winmain(eokim).120521-1311) FileDescription: IIS Express Worker Process Product: Internet Information Services ProductVersion: 8.0.8418.0 Debug: False Patched: False PreRelease: False PrivateBuild: True SpecialBuild: False Language: Language Neutral
```

The problem can be reproduced only when I choose "Modify"

[image: Proposition to modify Web.config]

Update5:

Here is simple reproduction example:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication2
{
public class DavHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.BufferOutput = false;

        Page page = (Page)System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
            "~/MyCustomHandlerPage.aspx", typeof(Page));
        page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
}
```

MyCustomHandlerPage.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Title="WebDAV" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family: Verdana; font-size:smaller; }
        li { padding-bottom: 7px; }
        input {width: 250px}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>"<%="TEST" %>"</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="RepositoryPath" value="~/App_Data/WebDAV/Storage"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

  <handlers>
    <clear />
    <add name="My WebDAV Handler" path="*" verb="*" type="WebApplication2.DavHandler, WebApplication2" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

If you run this example from Visual Studio 2013 in Internet Explorer and watch source for the resulting page you will see:

```
<p>"   TEST   "</p>
```

Then you can save the page as a file and look into it with HEX viewer. You will see those Byte order marks "EF BB BF" inserted. But not with any other Visual Studio version.

Update6:

This issue appears when project was created in VS 2013 in debug="true" mode. When I open this project from VS2010/2012 the same issue is present.
But when the project was created in VS2010/2012 the problem is absent.

Comment: You can download example here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797767/visual-studio-2010-2013-aspx-view-engine-inserts-extra-byte-order-marks-ef-bb-bf-in-debug-true-mode

Comment: The Problem is absent in Visual Studio 2013 RC.